# How to inject a Request object into a Twig template from a CLI unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, twig, symfony-2.8, php-5.5

I'm trying to unit test some Symfony 2.8 code that uses a Twig 1.24 template (I'm not actually testing the template). The template has a hard coded reference to `app.request`, which doesn't exist under the CLI:

```
{%
set currentPath = path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'),
app.request.attributes.get('_route_params'))
%}
```

I've tried injecting a new Request object into the container from within the test method:

```php
    $container->enterScope('request');
    $container->set('request', new Request(), 'request');
```

as recommended by other Symfony 2 answers, but I still get the following error:

```
1) InvoiceServiceTest: Should generate a pdf invoice
 Test  tests\unit\HMRX\CoreBundle\Services\InvoiceServiceTest.php:testShouldGenerateAPdfInvoice

  [Twig_Error_Runtime] Impossible to access an attribute ("attributes") on a null variable in "HMRXAppBundle:Invoice:invoice.html.twig" at line 2
```

How can I get around this limitation and get a Request object in the template under test? I don't think it needs to be particularly valid, it just needs to exist.

Comment: The `$container` being a reference to `app`?

Comment: @DarkBee https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container.html